# Multiple end for a rule in Drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I am completely new to Drools and just exploring. So far I had been using a single rule and withing which we use if conditions just like java.

Now I had to use complex rules where I need to use multiple if and else chain but to end it when one in the series of conditions satisfies.

I call the drools from the Apache Camel. The rules should reply back to Camel.

Now How do I do to break the chain of rules and then send response back to the caller which is Camel code when one of if and else condition fails.

1.Can I use multiple end statements to respond back?

2.I can use functions and I know is to write functions in java and import them.

3.Is there any possibility to create functions in Drools and use just like in java?

I am not using the Drools in the way it should be used but so far the rules had not been so complex as the one we are using them now . Any help is is useful for me.

Here is an example which I would like to use please suggest if the below would work or some other alternative like the below.

```
rule "my rule"
when
#some condition

then

 if(){

 end

 }else if(){

 #do something

 }

 if(){

  #do some other logic

}
 end
```

Sample after My second comment

```
When

object:SomeObject(); // This helps for my camel code to trigger this rule and this rule only

then

if(){

}
else if()
{

return;
}else if() {
}

if(){

}else if(){
return;
}
if(){

}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "breaking a chain of rules". Evaluating rules ends all by iteself, when there aren't any more rule activations to be executed,

Answers to 1. - 3.:

1. No. - There is no such thing I can associate with the term "respond back", but there aren't "multiple end statements [for one rule]".
2. Yes, you can use static Java function: import the class, call it, as in Java.
3. Yes. this is explained in the Drools manual, in a section with the title "Function". The example is from the manual:

   function String hello(String name) {
       return "Hello "+name+"!";
   }

**Comment on the rule added later to the question**

You cannot use `end` between `then` and the actual `end` of the rule. If you want to terminate the consequence part of a rule, use Java's `return` statement (without an expression, of course).

Reconsider using complex conditional statements in the consequence. Logic decisions should be expressed in the condition parts of rules.

**Much later** Workaround due to possible Guvnor bug - does not accept return;

```
boolean skip = false;
if(){
} else 
if() {
    skip = true; // return;
} else 
if() {
}
if( ! skip ){
    if(){
    } else
    if(){
        skip = true; // return;
    }
 }
if( ! skip ){
    if (){
    }
}
```

end

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw the function one. But i would like to code like a sample which I have added in my question now. Can you confirm with that?

Comment: @NaveenRaj Added a comment on the rule in my answer.

Comment: it says that void methods cannot return value. Can you help me ?

Comment: See my answer: "return statement ... **without an expression**"

Comment: I have given just "return;" I did not get without expression .. You mean in the when condition ? Please clarify me..

Comment: A statement `return;` is OK (not `return someStr;` or similar). But it could be something else - I can't tell without the rule code.

Comment: I have a similar code for this. Can you tell something on this? or do you need more info

Comment: This: `else if{ return;}else if {}` is not valid Java code.

Comment: This kind if if else conditions work in the then part and with my little experience it works but the issue i face is the return statement . which gives me error when validating with validate button in the guvnor. Any Ideas.

Comment: But the sequence of tokens in that line is **not valid Java code**. I won't answer questions based on it. - However, if you do have problems in Guvnor with correct return statements, it is a Guvnor issue, to be reported on Drools JIRA. - You can work around this issue by setting a flag and testing it subsequently.

Comment: Sorry the earlier one was a typo and I misunderstood that the series of if else could not be used. I have made relevant changes in my question . Please check if they are releveant

Comment: Thanks @laune I used functions to make a work around and am calling them in the drools file. I am testing them and let you know about it once completed